# Need help finding specs for RV1 & RV2 varistors on fried board

Tags: components, component-failure, component-values

[image][image]Power surge blew 6 appliances and am hoping I can repair some of the boards. I cannot identify blow varistors in RV1 & RV2 positions on Saeco IG 1.9.168.00_V04 board. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you post pictures of the blown varistors, we might be able to help you figure out their markings, but the odds of someone having that information to hand are pretty much zero.

Comment: I have pics but don’t see how to load into comments section

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information, and any information requested by a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking if you replace the MOVs with something rated for the **same voltage** and of **similar physical diameter** from a reputable manufacturer you'll be similarly protected. The disk diameter is typically something like 5, 7, 10, 14, 20mm and the measured diameter will be a couple mm larger because of the coating. That's assuming it's a plain Metal Oxide Varistor, in some cases they have been combined with other devices, but 99% of the time they're just varistors.

There are many thousands of possible part numbers, here is [just one](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2015602.pdf) datasheet from one maker.

Varistors are fairly sloppy devices and they may not have actually protected your board, in which case you may have a lot of work to do to find and replace the other damaged items. The device should work without the varistor installed (and any blown fuses replaced), it just won't be protected so the next power surge can kill a lot more stuff, so it's probably okay for a brief test to see if the board should be scrapped, but not recommended for longer term use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will check diameter.

Comment: The board controls an espresso machine. Since the power surge, the grind function is continuous when unit is assembled and powered on.

Comment: Assuming it still does that when the MOV has been removed, it sounds like something else (the device switching the grinder, possibly an alternistor or triac) is also fried. T2 is a prime suspect.